# C++ File Cin.ignore() function

Tags: c++, file

It could not work if I type the Name with the space such as Peter Stroll. How to use cin.ignore() in this case?

Thank you in advance.

```
int main()
{
    ofstream File("player.txt");

    cout << "Enter player ID, Name, and Money:" << endl;
    cout << "Press Ctrl + Z to quit \n" << endl;

    int id;
    string name;
    int age;

    while(cin >> id >> name >> age)
    {
        File << id << " " << name << " " << age << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you posting a picture rather than pasting the code here?

Comment: Are you trying to get it to read `Peter Stroll` into `name`, or just read `Peter`, `ignore` the error, and continue on...?

Comment: why specifically with cin.ignore() ?

Comment: The purpose of cin.ignore is to ignore certain number of characters or until finding a  character that matches to delimiter in the stream. I don't think that it is right way to solve this problem. Instead, you can use getline function and parse the string or you can read name and surname separately.

Comment: Here if we do not use the cin.ignore(). When we type name separate with any space it will ignore the left behind the space. Yes, Getline is the right solution but how can we use in this situation.?

Answer (score 0):

cin won't accept any more character if it encounters tab or space key.
use getline instead

char name[64] = {0};
cin.getline(name, 64);